# Multiple Rayon `spawn` with parallel iterators inside

Tags: multithreading, rust, iterator, rayon

I'm trying to speed up CPU-heavy computations in an async environment (tokio). My initial solution was to use `rayon::spawn` with a parallel iterator within to actually perform. A minimal example with pseudo-code:

```
for data in vec![data1, data2, data3] {
    rayon::spawn(move || {
        iproduct!(...)
            .par_bridge()
            .for_each(|...| process(data))
    })
}
```

This must be wrong, because when as is above, all tasks take 2h to run but if I remove `.par_bridge()` then the first task only takes 20min (as expected, since the first set of data is much smaller) while the rest take upwards of 4h.

I hope this isn't a case of XY problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a for loop and `rayon::spawn` rather than `data.into_par_iter().for_each(..)`?

Comment: I presented the data in a vector since it was a minimal example, but each set of data is collected from a REST API and the contents of the loop are called separately and at different moments in time. I have no actual way of collecting it all at once.

Comment: If your processing is relatively simple it's possible that the compiler sees through the workload and is able to vectorise it. With `par_bridge`, there's likely no such option.

Comment: You might have a resource exhaustion issue, like mutex contention, or maybe tokio's thread pool and rayon's thread pool fighting over CPU cores.